# I would like to make drag and drop in my Application Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, drag-and-drop

How can i Make a drag and drop with my Angular and Ionic application.

I tried many solution but I did not succeed .
Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable

Comment: Yes ... But it does not work , I feel that ionic blocks